# Set up a virtual LAN with a PC behind internal IP

Tags: router, ip, lan, nas

I have a Tonidoplug running on Ubuntu Linux at home which has a NAS attached to it. The problem is, the cheap Internet service provider that I am using at home basically only assigned me an internal (10.x.x.x) IP and possibly shared the IP with many other users before reaching over to the Internet.

In short, here is my set up at home at moment

NAS -> TonidoPlug (consider it like a small PC) -> Home Router -> Internal (10.x.x.x) IP -> service provider -> Internet

At the moment, I am mounting my NAS like a network drive when I am at home, so everything is nice and easy. However, I will be moving to another place temporarily for a few months soon so I am just wondering if there is any way I can continue to use it like a network drive in Windows without logging into different websites every time? The only solution I can think of is to create a virtual LAN somehow, but how to do it is something I hope you could help me as well.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

**EDIT**: I think I found out where the issue is, I have a VOIP box connected in front of my router, which I have completely forgot about, therefore, the router is actually using the the IP provided by the VOIP box, once I enabled port forwarding from VOIP box to the router and from router to my plug, everything works.

Sorry for the confusion and thanks a lot for everyone's help!

Comment: I find it hard to believe that you have a public IP address of 10.x.x.x. Please browse to http://www.whatsmyip.org/ to check. It would tell you what your public IP address is. Once you have that, you should be able to connect to your NAS with port forwarding.

Comment: @Stacey: [Carrier grade NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier_grade_NAT) is, unfortunately, not unheard of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin with, whilst I have never seen it myself, I have heard of some ISPs which give private IPs out, that being said, from your setup, are you sure that the TonidoPlug isn't taking the public IP and providing DHCP or similar with 10.x.x.x ip to the router, which will then be providing it's own DHCP to other machines?

(To test, try putting a switch between the TonidoPlug and the Router, and see if the other ports get different 10.x.x.x ips).

If however you are just on some bad ISP, I can still not really understand entirely what you are trying to accomplish.

If you are going to be away from this network and you want to try some sort of VPN so you can access you internal resources, your choices are limited due to (I am guessing) no port forwarding.

You can look at [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com) or [LogMeIn Hamachi](http://www.logmein.com) which are VPN solutions that can work under outgoing only connections using a third party service.